# List Manager cannot upload list of mails

Tags: list-manager

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8 and EXM enabled. I use EXM to send mail campaigns after extending the email facet to add two extra emails: Personal email and Work email. It was then working just fine however it now, List Manager crashes when uploading a sample file with the emails and no longer works.

after uploading the file and mapping the fields, i get the following error msg:
[image]

[image]
After checking the logs, i found two errors in the reporting logs:
the first one is as below:

> ERROR [Sitecore Services]: Failed to load Sitecore.ContentTesting.Requests.Controllers.PersonalizationRule.PersonalizationRuleController, Sitecore.ContentTesting

and the second one is:

> ERROR Exception
>   Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source: mscorlib
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
>
> Nested Exception
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: Unknown connection string. Name: 'web'
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultSettings.GetConnectionString(String connectionStringName)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromConnectionStringName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Properties.DefaultPropertyStoreProvider.ReadPropetiesStores()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Properties.DefaultPropertyStoreProvider.InitializeStoreProvider()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Properties.DefaultPropertyStoreProvider.get_DefaultStore()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Properties.DefaultPropertyStoreProvider.GetPropertyKeys(String prefix)
>      at Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.GetTicketKeyList()
>      at Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.GetTicketIDs()
>      at Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAuthenticationTicketsAgent.Run()

I read that the "Target invocation exception" is usually caused by a prior error but I'm not sure what does the first error means!

Can anyone help with how can I track the problem that causes the List Manager to crash?

Comment: For Clarity, this is not an EXM issue. As you use List Manager to upload contacts. I'm going to clean this up to reflect that.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail in the issue you are seeing and maybe some screenshots?  The errors you have provided have nothing to do with importing of contacts into List Manager.

Comment: @ Pete Navarra i updated the question with two screenshots of the errors i get, i wasn't sure these errors in the logs are the reason that EXM not working however i thought it might be causing a problem but you made it clear that it's not related to EXM

Comment: what is the format of your file?

Comment: i use a file with csv format

Comment: This is a key message: `Unknown connection string. Name: 'web' Source: Sitecore.Kernel` But none of these messages have anything to do with CSV uploads, List Manager, or EXM. Are you sure these are the errors actually being produced? Are there other errors in the log? And for clarity, you looking at the CM log, yes?

Comment: these errors are in the reporting logs on the cm server

Comment: Can you tell me what roles your CM server is set to? Just Content Management or more?

Comment: @Chris Auer the environment is scaled on 4 servers: one for cm, one for cd, one for SQL and one for SOLR. The cm server has under its wwwroot the following: reporting, processing, xconnectCollection, xconnectCollectionSearch, MarketingAutomation

Comment: @ Pete Navarra if this errors are not related to csv uploads, could you please me how can i track the cause problem ? i am not actually sure what might causing the errors in the screenshots